# Regex expression to invalidate numbers separated by comma

Tags: regex

I have to make a regex expression to invalidate numbers which are separated by comma.

1_2_3 - valid

1_2_3,1_3 - invalid

What I have so far: `([1-9+_]*[1-9]*[^,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^\d+(?:_\d+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WjdRvI/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `\d+`
- `)*` - zero or more occurrences of the pattern sequences in the group
- `$` - end of string.

Note: in case the flavor is JavaScript, it is fine to use `\d` to match any ASCII digit and it is equal to `[0-9]`. If you need to match any number without leading zeros still accepting a `0`, you may replace each `\d` with `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` construct that matches a `0` or a digit other than `0` followed with any zero or more digits.